# How to set an upper bound on a JuMP minimizing model?

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump

I would like to set an upper bound for my JuMP model. That is, given I am minimizing, all nodes and solutions that have a value higher than my upper bound should not be considered by JuMP. How should I do that? What could I have searched on [JuMP's documentation](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/search/?q=bound) or Google to find out? I tried `bound` but couldn't find anything.

Comment: One obvious way would be: `min z` subject to `z=objfun`, `z<=bound`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JuMP does not solve problems. Instead, it *formulates* them, and passes the solution off to a solver. You might want to read: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/background/algebraic_modeling_languages/

You can tell some solvers that there is a solution limit. For example, Gurobi has:
https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/cutoff.html#parameter:Cutoff

```
model = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)
set_optimizer_attribute(model, "Cutoff", 1000)
```

Note that this is specific to Gurobi. If you use a different solver, you will need to look at their documentation for the corresponding attribute (which may not exist).

Why do you want this? Cutoffs are rarely helpful.

Comment: I want to do this because my problem is the best solution between two sub-problems, one that I solve polynomially and another one that I solve with Gurobi. That's why I want Gurobi to avoid all solutions worse than my other algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a way to do so, I do not know if it is the way recommended but at least it works.

I use my objective as follows:

```
@objective(m, f(x,y))
```

While supposing that `f(x,y)` is defined for arrays `x` and `y`

Then I set a constraint on `f`:

```
threshold = 1000 # Or any other relevant value
@constrait(m, f(x,y) <= threshold)
```

Comment: You cannot use an inequality like this in `@objective`.

Comment: @Oscar Dowson, yes I have made a mistake, I wanted to write `@constraint`